# Setting additional headers in httpd.conf

Tags: apache, http-headers, httpd.conf

I am trying to set the GNU Terry Pratchett header for my Apache Server (see http://www.gnuterrypratchett.com/#apache).

In my previous server, I was able to add the following to `httpd.conf`:

```
<IfModule headers_module>
    header set X-Clacks-Overhead "GNU Terry Pratchett"
</IfModule>
```

That worked the, but I can’t get it working in my new server. I have also tried putting it in a separate file which I have called `hex.conf`.

When I execute `curl -I www.example.net` the header doesn’t appear.

I can get it working if I add the header in my `.htaccess` file, but I want to add it to the server configuration itself.

OK, so it’s not earth shattering, but the broader question is whether something has changed regarding settings in `httpd.conf`.

As regards versions:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.37 (rocky)
Server built:   Jan 25 2022 16:26:44
```

Comment: The config block in question contains a conditional. You might simply not have the headers module available

Comment: @OlafKock It never occurred to me to check that. However `apachectl -M | grep headers` returns `headers_module (shared)`, so I suppose it is available.